# Cross database joins in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

I have two separate databases with the same credentials: db1 have a table with a column containing filepaths that I need to build with a filename that is stored in db2 and that I can retrieve using an ID.
ID is set in a Joomla Fabrik form that on submission run a PHP function and store ID in db1.
I have set the following code on the form submission php plgin, but when I submit the form there isn't any change in filepath column as I'm expected:

```
$galleryId = '{field_placeholder}';

if (!empty($galleryId)) {
   $myDb = JFactory::getDbo();
   $myQuery = "
      UPDATE db1.table1
      SET db1.table1.filepath =
        CONCAT('/path/', db2.table2.imgfilename)
      WHERE db2.table2.id = '$galleryId'
";
   $myDb->setQuery($myQuery);
   $myDb->execute();
}
```

where `caduti___id_joomgallery` is the ID full element name (fabrik placeholder), `galleryID` is the image ref number in db2 that is stored in db1 to make the join. The form is stored in db2 (joomla system db).

Edit:
I was able to set an sql query that work as expected in phpmyadmin. I have tested it substituting `$galleryID` with a real value.
But when i put the query inside php code, it return a 500 server error in mozilla console.

```
$galleryId = '{field_placeholder}';
if (!empty($galleryId)) {
   $myDb = JFactory::getDbo();
   $myQuery = "
  UPDATE db1.table1
    SET filepath= CONCAT("/path/",(SELECT imgfilename FROM db2.table2 where id=$galleryId))
    WHERE id_gallery = $galleryId
  ";
   $myDb->setQuery($myQuery);
   $myDb->execute();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might also want to consider asking this on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. I immediately wonder what are the values of $galleryId, db1.caduti & db2.xxx_joomgallery & whether a trivial query or update works. Also what "tried this function" & "nothing happens" mean.

Comment: did you try `echo $myQuery; exit;` and putting this in the db manually. I am quite sure that `WHERE db2.xxx_joomgallery.id = '{caduti___id_joomgallery_raw}'` is not what you want.

Comment: I have edit the code as requested and investigated about sql query that now work. But php code doesn't, so I need further help.